# In Android, why won't the SQLite Database update?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm attempting to update a row using:

`myDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" + mName, null);`

but I get the following error:

**ERROR/Database(282): Error updating persons_name=Bob using UPDATE peopleTable SET persons_name=? WHERE persons_name=Bob**

I am using the following code to attempt the update:

```
public void updateEntry(String mName) throws SQLException {

    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mName);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" + mName, null);

}
```

I have looked at other answers which seem to be similar to this problem but I have not found something definitive that solves the problem which I am having. It appears to be something to do with the variables but I may be completely wrong..

Comment: instead of KEY_NAME + "=" + mName try to use KEY_NAME + " like " + mName or KEY_NAME + "=" + "'"+mName+ "'"+ or something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not enclosing your string in quotes. You're better off doing something like this:

```
ourDatabase.update(DATEABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "= ?", new String[]{mName});
```

when you use the above, it will automatically enclose the param in single-quotes if the type is a string.

Answer (score 4):

"persons_name=Bob" should probably be "persons_name='Bob'", so try:

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "='" + mName + "'", null);
```